# How to publish directly on facebook or on twitter using Sharekit in IOS

Tags: sharekit, facebook-sharer

I have used sharekit in my iPhone project to publish on facebook and on twitter.

But at every time when I share on facebook or twitter there is one popup coming and on that send button click content will be share.

The issue is that I don't want this popup and want to publish directly on Facebook or on twitter.

Please give Idea if anybody has.

Comment: wonder why down votes? To answer the question, autoshare is currently not implemented on ShareKit for Twitter or Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In SHKFacebook.m and SHKTwitter.m there is one function **"shouldAutoShare"**
It should **return yes** and your probleb is solved.

My problem is solved with this I hope it's also helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Hardik Shah.. Thanks for your answer it helps. what code i have to use to send the post.. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi, Vinoth

The basic sharing code is below.

SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sharing text goes here..."]];
[SHK setRootViewController:self];
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];


But you need more configuration and settings for that use below link.

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

I hope it will help you and your problem will solved.

Comment: Hi Hardik, Thanks for your link which i have done it perfectly.. what i am looking for is how to post direct messages to the facebook instead of any dialog boxes..